# The data is invalid. (13) . AAPT2 . file missing

Tags: android, kotlin, missing-data, aapt2

One of the autogenerated files (R file) is showing missing while building the project.

ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.0"

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'

compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer Update :

The **Antivirus was** interfering and **capturing** the **autogenerated file** as false positive.
Ignoring the file or Add to exception or Allowing the Program in antivirus solved the problem.